# Understanding Claims in Tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net, claims-based-identity

I've set up my solution to generate JWT tokens with Claims inside of them. However, I don't understand at which point I should add claims after getting the user identity:
`var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);`

Should I get the user information, say Email from the identity and then add a `new Claim()` on the fly?

I can't get a good understanding of the concept...

Say, I registered a couple of users but user'A' has different claims than user'B' how can I differentiate this after calling `CreateIdentityAsync`?

Thanks